# Solved Why is this way of adding not working?

Tags: arithmetic

I'm making a calculator as a school project.
It works by solving each 2 members of an operation ;
Concretely, if I type "2+3-5+4-2+6-7+1", it calculates "(2+3)-(5+4)-(2+6)-(7+1)"
Why is it wrong ?

Comment: The distributivity law: for instance, in your example above, $-5 +4 = -(5-4)$.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am making a calculator". Does this mean you are programming an application to do this? If so, how in the world do you expect us to know what the problem with the application is if we don't even see what it does?

Comment: ooh thank you that's right

Comment: and yes i am programming it, but i explained how it works, and peter a g understood it as expected.

Comment: Why is it wrong? Because we have decided through the centuries that that's not how addition and subtraction interact. It could've been correct, but it isn't.

Comment: @Jacques You most certainly did not "explain how it works". Peter a g **guessed**, correctly, and understood the way you wanted him to. **I** read the same thing, and understood it as "My calculator calculates (2+3)-(5+4)-(2+6)-(7+1), which I know is wrong, but why does it calculate this way?".

Comment: @5xum 'Guessed'? I prefer - (a coronavirus free) cough - 'surmised'...

Comment: "*I'm making a calculator as a school project*"  That sounds rather ambitious if you are truly doing it from the ground up and from first principles... If you are simply *coding* a calculator instead, then it might help to interpret $2+3-5+4-2+6-7+1$ instead as $2+3+(-5)+4+(-2)+6+(-7)+1$, eliminating the need to think about subtractions and instead only think about adding and additive inverses.  Actually physically building the logic gates necessary to handle multiple inputs, while interesting, seems outside the usual scope of such a project...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is the distributive law, for example consider $-7+1$: your program will display $-(7+1)=-8$, but this is incorrect. Instead, if you use the distributive law, you have: $$-7+1=-(7-1)=-6$$

Comment: @Jacques: if it has been useful, maybe a $+1$?

Comment: Sure I've done it, but it's not displayed since I have less than 15 rep